# Showing a tab only when another tab is clicked and/or active?

Tags: jquery

I have another quick question. I have a set of DIV's that act as Tabs. (Similar to jQueryUI's Tabs). My question is this, and it should contain a short and concise answer (I hope =P).

I want to know how to change my existing JS (Shown Below), to where when a tab with an ID of #tab-2 is clicked, or is active (whichever is better or even both, idk), then and only then, show the tab with the ID of #tab-4.

This way, when a user clicks on #tab-2, #tab-4 appears. If #tab-2 is not clicked or active, tab 4 is hidden.

I thought this would be easy, and maybe I am over analyzing it, but here is my JS:

```
$(function() {
if $('#tab-2').click(function() {
    $('#tab-4').show();
    };
else $('#tab-4').hide();
    };
});
```

});

HTML Update:

CANNOT UPDATE BECAUSE SO's CODE EDITOR IS CRAP IMO. Look at https://jqueryui.com/tabs/ for a great reference.

Does this look good, all I know is it doesn't work for some reason lol. Any help is appreciated. =)

Comment: Personally, I would use CSS. Apply a class to the parent of both tabs. `.show-tabs-2-4` would show both tabs, while `.show-tabs-2` would be a specific tab.

Comment: @Jack Pattishall Jr.: Elaborate please? Maybe show me some code? JSFiddle..? Also, I would prefer to use jQuery if that helps any but if you show me a decent CSS alternative, I would be happy to try it... =) Thanks in advance...

Comment: @user3267537 it's doable in pure CSS, but it's not user friendly and implies the use of additional HTML elements `label` and `checkboxes`. Quite a mess.

Comment: @user3267537 it's not crap, it's just you than don't know how to use it :) Next time leave the code in place, we can edit it until you learn how to properly use the HTML markup editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there

`if $('#tab-2').click(function() {` is wrong, and some misplaced `;`.

```
$(function() { // DOM ready shorthand

  $('#tab-2').click(function() {
      $('#tab-4').toggle();
  });                         

});
```

It would help also that you use a selector that points to ALL of your tabs, so when you waht first to close them all you can do something like: `$('.tab').hide(); // First, hide all...`

By seeing your HTML I would surely give you a better advice... Till than.

Comment: It didnt seem to work. I was certain that I would need to use Boolean to perform this. Butt then again I am still adapting to JS and JQ lol. Also, I updated the OP to show the HTML... Or, https://jqueryui.com/tabs/ can get you a good idea of it.

Comment: @user3267537 can you explain *what's not working*? What's the expected result? Your question is not that clear at all.

Comment: Side Note, I am not familiar with the code editor in SO, you're right lol. But the expected result is that, Tab 4 is hidden, until tab 2 is clicked/active. If tab 2 is not active/clicked, then Tab 4 is hidden from view. Meaning that Tab 4 is only visible when Tab 1 is clicked or active. Which is why I though and used Boolean to say if tab 2 is clicked ID #tab-2 is clicked, .show #tab-4. Else, .hide #tab-4. Thanks in advance =)

Comment: @user3267537 that's exactly what my code does if you take in consideration that hopefully you initially hided it using CSS `display:none;`

Comment: @user3267537 also interesting that you now use the selector `tab-1` but in your question you say `tab-2` ...

Comment: Thank you for the most prompt of replies =D. Where would I place that CSS at? Do I place it in #tab-4's HTML/CSS?Thanks again =) Also, sry for all the questions, I am very tired and my brain is on overload lol =P And about Tab-1 and Tab-2, my apologies I am doing like 50 things at once lmao

Comment: @user3267537 please, setup a demo HTML in jsBin.com and share a link in comment.

Comment: No need, you answered me lol. I was just being an idiot and not putting the "display: none" in the right spot of the HTML lol. Thank you so much =D

Comment: @user3267537 you're welcome! don't forget to sleep! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with the selected answer, but you asked for me to elaborate :) Here's a quick JS Fiddle that demonstrates what I suggested.

Firstly, the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GY356/

The main difference is that instead of using jQuery to show/hide elements directly (by calling `$(this).show()`, `$(this).hide()`, or `$(this).toggle()`), we set a class on the parent (in our case, the `id` of the clicked tab).